# Creating video frame with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Trying to create an img element with a frame from a video that user selects with a html input. The file enters in the "if" but only shows a black square in the table and the name of the file and not a frame from the video.

```
if(fileList[i].type === "video/"+Video[j]){  

        var video = document.createElement('video');
        video.src=(window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[i]).replace('blob:',''));
        video.pause();
        video.muted = true;
        video.playsInline = true;
        video.play();

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 50;
            canvas.height = 50;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
convert to desired file format

var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
Table for Videos

for( var lV=0; lV<100; lV++ ){  
            // if for name
        if(fileList[i].name===NameFile[lV]){    

    var Vx = document.createElement("Table");
    Vx.setAttribute("id", "galeriaV" + (i));
    document.body.appendChild(Vx);
imagens of videos

var VImg = document.createElement("tr");
    VImg.setAttribute("id", "VTr" +(i));
    document.getElementById("galeriaV" +(i)).appendChild(VImg);
var ImgV = document.createElement("td");
var imagV =document.createElement("img");
imagV.setAttribute("id", "imageID" +(i));
imagV.setAttribute("className", "bordered");
imagV.setAttribute("src","http://placehold.it/200/200/pink/black");
imagV.setAttribute("onclick","imgClick(this)"); 

  imagV.src = dataURI;
  imagV.height = 50;
  imagV.with = 50; 

ImgV.appendChild(imagV);
document.getElementById("VTr" + (i)).appendChild(ImgV);
```

files names

```
var yV = document.createElement("tr");
    yV.setAttribute("id", "VNTr" + (i));
    document.getElementById("galeriaV" +(i)).appendChild(yV);

    var Vz = document.createElement("td");
    var Vt = document.createTextNode(NameFile[lV]);
    Vz.appendChild(Vt);
    document.getElementById("VNTr" + (i)).appendChild(Vz);
}
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Loading and seeking a video frame are both asynchronous operations. So at the time you draw your vid, nothing is available there.

Comment: So how can i do this?

Comment: Wait for the different events that the HTMLMediaElement interface offers. E.g onloadedmetadata is the first one you'll want to listen to. But the first frame of the video is often black, so you may also want to set its currentTime to a small amount, and in this case you'd listen for onseeked event.

Comment: so add an onloadevent, that after the video is loaded create the canvas?